# Provision property bag for document library declaratively via sandbox

Tags: document-library, sandbox-solution, provisioning, property-bag

I have a no-code sandbox solution that I use to provision artefacts.
One is a document library to which I want to attach a property bag to be set by a user via custom setting page.

I learned that one can not directly attach a property bag to a document library but only to its root folder.
I know how to add property bags to items but did not succeed in adding those to a root folder.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Margriet Bruggeman over at [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/053e00d4-b322-40af-852a-4be9b5c9212a/provision-property-bag-for-document-library-declaratively-via-sandbox?forum=sharepointdevelopment): its not possible to declaratively add a property bag to the root folder. However it is via CSOM.

Solution: I - in any case - need a custom list settings link with attached configuration page to set/modify the property bag (via JSOM). Now I will use this very page to first check if there is a property bag and if not I'll simply create it.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the property bag of the root folder of the document library using this code snippet.

```
    //Load the document library and the root folder objects
    ctx.Load(oDocLib);
    ctx.Load(oDocLib.RootFolder);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    // Create/update the root folder properties
    oDocLib.RootFolder.Properties["Your_Custom_Property"] = "true"; // this is the same command to create and update a propety in  the property bag
    oDocLib.RootFolder.Update();
    oDocLib.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

The same can be done using javascript also.